# SAS macro variable used in prompt as a default value

Tags: variables, macros, sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have a SAS macro variable LAST_RUN_DATE. 
Then I have a prompt in which a user can select a date and run the program.

For this prompt, I'd like to set a default value which would come from LAST_RUN_DATE macro variable. However, I can only see a list of predefined values that can be used as a default value. Is this possible?

If not, can you at least pass it to the prompt description and use it there? I tried saying &LAST_RUN_DATE in the description but that didn't work.

Comment: Please share the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I haven't tried any code, not sure how you can write any code to the prompt?

Comment: How to prompt for user input depends on how you are running SAS.  It is different when using SAS Display Manager than in Enterprise Guide or SAS/Studio or one of the many other ways to run SAS code.  How are your intended users running SAS?

Comment: We are using Enterprise Guide.

Comment: Prompt definitions or attributes can't be defined by macro variables.  You can update the prompt definition using SAS, though, and could write a program to update the default value (the program would be executed on a periodic basis), if you think that would work for you.

Comment: Are you running this on a server (with a metadata server running also)?